# BigQuery standart SQL - how to calculate 2 timestamp2 difference in minutes

Tags: date, google-bigquery, difference, bigdata

I'm using BigQuery standart SQL and i need to find the difference between 2 timestamps, in minutes.

For example:

Timestamp1 = '2016-10-10 09:40:00'   |
Timestamp2 = '2016-10-10 09:50:00'

I want to return the difference:

Timestamp2-Timestamp1 = 10

I found how to do it with Legacy SQL, but it doesn't help:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#datediff

Thank you !

Comment: If you're looking for the equivalent to a legacy SQL function using standard SQL, the migration guide has a table that can often help: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/migrating-from-legacy-sql#function_comparison.

Answer (score 2):

check for [TIMESTAMP_DIFF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#regexp_contains) function

```
SELECT
  TIMESTAMP "2016-10-10 09:50:00" as first_timestamp,
  TIMESTAMP "2016-10-10 09:40:00" as second_timestamp,
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP "2016-10-10 09:50:00",
    TIMESTAMP "2016-10-10 09:40:00", MINUTE) AS minutes;
```